# Python instead of being interpreted shows compiled behaviour

Tags: python, compilation, interpreter

I have read that python is a scripting language and its execution engine consists of a interpreter that executes each code of line one by one.
 I have a simple python code as-

```
print("1")
print("2")
print("3")
print("4)
```

Here line 4 print("4) contains an error(missing ending quote). When I run this program then simply get an error telling me a syntax error in line 4. 
 My question is that since python is interpreted and not compiled then shouldn't the output be

```
1
2
3
Syntax error in line 4
```

But it directly gives me a error message without any output for line 1, 2 and 3 just like any other compiled language like Java, C and C++ 
I'm new to python, Kindly explain.

Comment: Python code is initially compiled into bytecode that is interpreted by its virtual machine. The error you see comes from the compilation step. BTW, if by compilation you mean translation into machine code, then pre-JIT Java was not a compiled language either.

Comment: So your information is wrong. CPython is a compiler, but the compilation and execution step is not separated like with other compilers, e.g. Java.

Comment: @Daniel sorry I didn't got you. Please elaborate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important to realise that Python code is first compiled into an intermediate form called byte code. That byte code is then executed by the Python interpreter. It is analogous to the compilation/execution cycle of Java, if you are familiar with that, although Python can immediately execute the compiled code. The byte code is not the same as machine code that can be directly executed by the hardware, it is higher level.

In Python the compilation unit is the *module* which typically corresponds to a whole file, not individual statements.

So line 4 in your example will be compiled together with the previous lines, and the syntax error in line 4 prevents execution beginning.

You can get a feel for what the byte code is like by disassembling a function:

```
import dis

def f():
    print("1")
    print("2")
    print("3")

dis.dis(f)
```

Output

```
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('1')
              3 PRINT_ITEM          
              4 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  3           5 LOAD_CONST               2 ('2')
              8 PRINT_ITEM          
              9 PRINT_NEWLINE       

  4          10 LOAD_CONST               3 ('3')
             13 PRINT_ITEM          
             14 PRINT_NEWLINE       
             15 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Ohh. So basically the execution of python is just like java. Can you tell me where can I find its bytecode file ?

Comment: Kind of. My comparison to Java was intended to convey the fact that an intermediate code is executed by an interpreter/virtual machine, not directly on the hardware. Compiled Python code is written to `.pyc` files. You need to import the Python file to have it generate the `.pyc` file. Simply executing the script does not create one.

Comment: Sorry the syntax dis. dis(f)  is known to me.. Please explain

Comment: There are plenty of resources (including the Python interpreter source code) that can help you, if you really need to understand the disassembled code. A discussion of that is beyond the scope of the question.

Comment: Ohhkay.. And what about a python shell prompt. The commands that I type on the prompt are also compiled to one line bytecode and then interpreted(executed) or is directly interpreted ?

Comment: The interpreter is different when stdin is connected to terminal. It enters a Read–eval–print loop that will evaulate code as is it entered. To do that it needs to compile the code and then execute it. You can try this using `co = compile('<code>', '', 'single')` and then `eval(co)` to evaluate.